# In which UI component/s should filters and/or sorting be used?

Tags: android, filter, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

### Background

I'm making an alternative to the default app-manager app ([**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)), and currently I have 4 sorting options and one filtering option:

- sort by install time, update time, package name and app name
- include system apps or not

This can be shown here:

[image]

As you can see, both filtering and sorting are shown here via the action bar submenu, and I think I should do it differently.

### The problem

I wish to add more features for filtering and I think the current implementation would not suffice.

I've read through the guidelines ([**here**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html) and [**here**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)) and I'm not sure if a navigation drawer should be used , and maybe I should use the "View control" (link [**here**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)) component on the action bar for the sorting part or not.

### The question

How should I address this?

Is there any clear rule about where to put filters options (of the data being shown to the user)?

What about the sorting features?

Comment: I think it's a great question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcoAcierno didn't know it exists, but I'm not sure how well people know the various UI solutions of Android there. I also wonder why not merge all of the varios SO-like website into a single one and just put tags/types for the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, a navigation drawer doesn't sound appropriate. It's more targeted at getting around between different activities/screens.

The View Control dropdown doesn't seem to fit either; you're not really changing views/accounts or anything, just reorganizing what's already there.

If I were you, I'd change the sort settings ActionBar item to open a dialog instead of a dropdown. You could have your checkboxes there, and a spinner for which field to sort by.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it too, but Google also says dialogs should be avoided when possible. Plus I think it's easier to use the navigation drawer than dialogs, and the "view control" would at least show what is the current sorting the user has chosen. Also, I would need to decide what to do with all the extra space for tablets, as now the app works there too but probably not show so nicely...

Comment: Where do they advise against dialogs?

Comment: in one of their videos, and I think on some page of the guidelines. Sadly, when I tried to show this proof to someone, the only thing I've found is about progressDialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html , but i'm very sure I saw that they want developers to minimize the usage of dialogs.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well then it seems like there isn't a "right" way to do this, so whatever you choose will just be your preference for the layout you like best, not necessarily based on known best practices.

Comment: Do you know perhaps of well known apps that handled a similar problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked Google Drive. They have "Filter by" and "Sort by" in the app menu (accessed by pressing the menu key). When you select one it opens a dialog.

Comment: it's a bit different, since they have a lot of action items, and the filtering is by a single criteria (single item to choose), while I wish to add a combination.

Comment: I'm not trying to convince you to do it this way, just answering your questions. It seems you've already decided what you're going to do, I suggest you go ahead and do it and good luck.

Comment: no , I haven't decided. Looking at the screenshots of Google drive on tablets, I think they've left the sorting and filtering on the overflow menu item. Anyway, I think I will try out what you've suggested, and see how it goes. Thanks.